# How do I run a vpn on my ubuntu computer and access with my android

Tags: android, vpn

I want to access the internet and do other stuff on my Android phone I want to use my computer as a source of that vpn connection. I used to use Team viewer but they don't use VPN for the mobile app. i  I would also want to use my computers processing power rather than my phone but that is optional any other ways things like accessing my files on my computer would also optional but those arent required. if it has an interface between the devices then that would be grate

Answer (score 0):

OpenVPN is a good way to go and there are plenty of tutorials on how to set this up.

Just remember that Android and iOS only support the TUN interface and not TAP. You will understand once you start reading the tuts!